# Powershell - install-windowsfeature - name

Tags: powershell

When inputting in powershell the following:

install-windowsfeature -name

How do I get a list of available features to install?

Comment: On what system are these commands available? I have PowerShell 5.1 and `Get-Command *windows*` shows no PowerShell commands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this you would want to use another cmdlet. **[Get-WindowsFeature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/servermanager/get-windowsfeature?view=winserver2012r2-ps)**

> Gets information about Windows Server roles, role services, and features that are available for installation and installed on a specified server.

Comment: That solved my problem.  Doing that, I see the list now of windows features, and was able to run install-windowsfeature -name NPAS